# Card is overflowing outside its column bounds

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using the following to show a list horizontally or vertically depending on the screen size.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="d-md-none">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
                    <li class="list-group-item border-0">
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" @onclick="">
                            <i class="fas fa-search" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item border-0">
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" @onclick="">
                            <i class="fas fa-address-card" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-none d-md-block">
     <!-- Here the list vertically !--> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when viewed on mobile devices, the card overflows out of its div. What can I change to make this not happen? Can I decrease the spacing between the items?

[image: Overflow]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example ?  
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Decreasing the spacing will make it harder to tap the correct icon.
Using media queries, you could write styling that applies to mobile (small screens) only. 
You could make the icons appear in two rows or make the box scrollable to make the overflowed items reachable.